# Instagram api is lake a very basic thing -getting user data

Tags: api, instagram

When user is log in with `instagram api`, with :

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

He than gets an access token to use ,and no data returned on the user .

Than , if you want to get your `user id` , or the `user name` , there is no way to do that ,

You have this :

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

But this will give you the user name -by his id . **I DONT HAVE HIS ID, OR HIS NAME.**
I just couldn't find any way to get the user details when log in , or after it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not mention anywhere in their API , and its a shame for a company that big .

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?access_token=
```